# Why would the Empire under Palpatine have a War on Drugs?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

OK, I can sort of see why the Old Republic may prohibit spice smuggling (same arguments fuelling War on Drugs in modern democracies).

But... why would the Empire under Sith Lord Palpatine bother doing so?

- Palpatine clearly has no big concern over the well being of the Imperial citizens, being a Sith Lord and all.
- Palpatine - or at least, his top circle - clearly cares about Imperial logistics and resources (as we see in canon, e.g. in "A New Dawn", "Tarkin" etc...). And legalizing spice and taxing the heck out of it seems like a good way to earn a parsec worth of money - as opposed to waste same such money - and Imperial fleet's resources - on barely effective anti-smuggling patrols, while letting Hutts and other criminals make all the profits off of smuggling.

Comment: Canon-based answers only please. Either Darth Mickey canon, or EU any level.

Comment: Not really a full answer but more of an aside: Sidious came into power through deception and trickery, it's likely he still needs to 'keep up appearances' of actually doing things that regular people care about. That and he was power hungry and enjoyed the control he had over everyone at every time. What other excuse does a power-lusting Sith Lord need? :P

Comment: “Palpatine clearly has no big concern over the well being of the Imperial citizens” — the American “War on Drugs” has no concern over the well-being of American citizens either.

Comment: @DVK +1 for 'Darth Mickey'...

Comment: @PhilPursglove [Especially in the context of this question.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn_%28drugs%29)

Comment: In the Jedi Academy trilogy by Kevin J Anderson, Han visits the Kessel spice mines where it is suggested that before the fall of the Empire they were in fact run by them -- so the "war on drugs" may be more about maintaining a monopoly than anything else.

Comment: Notice they are against *smuggling*, not necessarily against approved traders of spice. Smugglers smuggle not just because what they ship is illegal but to avoid taxes / import duty (in many countries smuggling untaxed tobacco is quite a lucrative criminal enterprise).

Comment: @TZHX That's a great observation - protectionism was always a great source of income (and power) in Earth's empires (and other interventionist governments).

Comment: Because drugs are bad m'kay.

Comment: @Richard - you sound like Sidious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going back to the old EU, Spice, Glitterstem, that was mined on Kessel had legitimate medical applications.  It also has the ability to grant some users near Force-like mental abilities for a short time.  This was mentioned in the Jedi Academy series when Han is trying to gain support for the New Republic from some of the more fringe elements of the galaxy.  Interrogators would sometimes use Glitterstem to help read information out of a suspect's mind, for example.

If Kessel Glitterstem Spice could grant that kind of mental boost to some of the population, probably Force Sensitives too weak to develop any true abilities, then any government would want to keep it controlled.  Otherwise anybody just getting too close to a nervous government official could be a potential spy on Glitterstem picking up secret information.

Additionally Spice addicts, Biters, become paranoid and violent, as mentioned in I, Jedi.  A distracted population is easy to manipulate.  A population drugged beyond coherent thought or fearful of crazed killers in its midst loses its productivity.

Answer (score 15):

Having a 'War on Drugs' is an extremely useful way of cracking down on dissident citizens. 'Drugs' is a really good excuse for locking up lots of people, conducting searches, prohibiting movement, etc. Merely suspecting someone of drug possession is a good reason to raid their home, and lock them up for a short time. Also drugs are really small, and easy to plant on people. One dishonest stormtrooper in a raid party is all you need to suddenly find drugs in your suspect's residence. People will in general agree to all sorts of police actions if they think drugs are involved.  In short a war on drugs can be great cover for some serious oppression.

Just as well this has never occurred to any governments in our galaxy.

Comment: Is there **any** canon support that the Empire, indeed, did what your answer implies? The only canon examples I'm aware of was genuine going after actual smugglers.

Comment: @DVK The only "dissidents" we see in canon are the Rebels and similar organizations, really - they're quite far removed from the Empire, and the Emperor would have no need to use this kind of lie against them. People who stayed in contact were usually a bit too high to get rid of that way - noöne would really believe a drug scandal with Mon Mothma or Leia Organa. The only reference we have of the drug war *are* with actual smugglers, but that's only because of Han and the Hutts, mostly - important characters for other reasons. The Emperor still needs public support as we know.